Power Bi Design Properties Connector - Derivative Record
I'm admittedly very inexperienced with the APS but have been following a number of the tutorials provided on GitHub; I created an issue on GitHub but am hoping here might be better to help resolve! GitHub issue here
I've successfully built the .mez file for the Design Properties Connector, but when attempting to pull in data from the connector, I am receiving the following:

Expression.Error: The field 'derivatives' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
item=[Record]
links=[Record]
refs=[Record]
downloadFormats=[Record]
Power Query Connector not finding derivatives

This occurs with any Document within my project files and these versions/derivatives appear correctly via the APS VSCode Extension.
Additionally, when navigating the table view within PowerQuery, the Name column produces the following error:

Expression.Error: 1 arguments were passed to a function which expects between 2 and 3.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=[List]

Version name issue
I've identified that the Name column is produced from GetItemVersions > GetVersionDetails within DataManagement.pqm passing to GetItemVersionNavigationTable in DesignPropsConnector.pq; given the version name is not being produced, and the derivatives field is not being found, I am assuming there is an issue with acquiring the item version from the document, but I'm not sure how to resolve.
I have tried modifying the code within the DataManagement.pqm and NavigationTable to have clearer error handling for if there is no data, and/or to generate the version name differently, but have not been successful. Any help is appreciated!
